# How to choose the method that overrides a method of superclass in constructor?

Tags: python, oop

I like to override one of the methods of a superclass and have different options for the target method. For example, the function in superclass is called `__func__` and I have two implementations `__func1` and `__func2` that implement `__func__`. I would like to choose one of these two functions **in the constructor** based on user's input. I have tried a few things I could think of, but none of them worked. Is this at all possible? If yes, what is the right way of doing it?

EDIT: my class uses `__slots__` to define the member variables, so I cannot use something like `self.__func__ = self.__func1`

Comment: Don't create your own double underscore methods.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah it is possible. Here’s a code sample in the child class. No changes needed in the parent class:

```
 def __init__(self, user_input):
    if (condition 1):
       self.__func__ = self.func1
    else:
       self.__func__ = self.func2

 def __func1(self, your arguments):
    code

 def __func2(self, your arguments)
    other code
```

As I do not know the arguments of the functions or the condition, this is as specific as I can get.

Comment: The thing is that I have user's input in constructor and don't want to store it. So I like to be able to set the appropriate function during construction.

Comment: Oh sorry, yh I’ll modify my answer. It is feasible.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is correct in general, but I forgot to say that my class uses __slots__ to define the member variables, so I cannot use something like `self.__func__ = self.__func1`.

Comment: You could use this with slots, only the function direction would not be in your `__slots__`  dict. Here is a good example: http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/__slots__magic.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to store the user input from `__init__` into an instance attribute:

```
class Parent(object):

    def func(self):
        raise NotImplementedError


class Child(Parent):

    def __init__(self, user_input):
        self.user_input = user_input

    def func(self):
        if self.user_input == "func1":
            self._func1()
        elif self.user_input == "func2":
            self._func2()
        else:
            # make sure to guard against other possible inputs!

    def _func1(self):
        # implementation here

    def _func2(self):
        # implementation here
```

EDIT: Here's a simple variant that doesn't store the user input. There are other, more complicated ways to do this perhaps. But this is one of the simplest:

```
class Parent(object):

    def func(self):
        raise NotImplementedError


class Child(Parent):

    def __init__(self, user_input):
        if user_input == "func1":
            self.func = self._func1
        elif user_input == "func2":
            self.func = self._func2
        else:
            pass
            # make sure to guard against other possible inputs!

    def _func1(self):
        print("from func1!")

    def _func2(self):
        print("from func12")
```

Comment: The thing is that I have user's input in constructor and don't want to store it. So I like to be able to set the appropriate function during construction.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is correct in general, but I forgot to say that my class uses __slots__ to define the member variables, so I cannot use something like `self.__func__ = self.__func1`.

Comment: You can also put `func1` outside of the class body and it will still work so long as you specify the first parameter correctly (canonically `self`).

Answer (score 1):

```
class Subclass(Superclass):
    def __init__(self, choice=True, *args, **kwargs)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.choice=choice

    def __func__(self):
        if self.choice:
            return self.__func1()
        else:
            return self.__func2()

   def __func1(self):
       do something

   def __func2(self):
       do something
```

Comment: The thing is that I have user's input in constructor and don't want to store it. So I like to be able to set the appropriate function during construction.